# JSON column as Key in kafka producer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

As we know , we can send a key with kafka producer which is hashed internally to find which partition in topic data goes to.
I have a producer , where in I am sending a data in JSON format.

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic USERPROFILE << EOF 
{"user_id" : 100, "firstname":"Punit","lastname":"Gupta", "countrycode":"IN", "rating":4.9 }
{"user_id" : 101, "firstname":"eli","lastname":"eli", "countrycode":"GB", "rating":3.0 }
EOF
```

Now I want to use "countrycode" as my key , while sending data.
In Normal delimited data we can specify 2 parameters :

```
--property "parse.key=true" 
--property "key.separator=:
```

But How to do it when sending JSON sata.

I am using confluent's python API for Kafka if there is any thing that I have to write in terms of classed of functions to achieve this, i would be thankful if you can say it in terms of python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is just a string. The console producer doesn't parse JSON, only the Avro console producer does.

I would avoid `key.separator=:` since JSON contains `:`. You could use `|` character instead, then you just type out

```
countrycode|{"your":"data"}
```

In Python, [the produce function takes a key, yes](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/#confluent_kafka.Producer.produce). You can parse your data like this in order to extract a value to the key.

```
key = 'countrycode'
records = [{"user_id" : 100, "firstname":"Punit","lastname":"Gupta", key:"IN", "rating":4.9 },
           {"user_id" : 101, "firstname":"eli","lastname":"eli", key:"GB", "rating":3.0 }
]

import json
for r in records:
    producer.produce('topic', key=r[key], value=json.dumps(r))
    # first record will send a record containing ('IN', {  ... 'countrycode':'IN'})
```

Comment: can you give me an example from my from producer above.

Comment: You need to duplicate the data from the value into the key. You can't parse the JSON while it's being produced in the console producer without some extra bash functions

Comment: but this will invalidate entire purpose of kafka, if i am using cpu for producing data , right ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... You are using CPU no matter what. Your producers shouldn't be running on the same machine as the brokers, so the CPU would be different in a real-world scenario.

Comment: please don't take me wrong , i am very new here , i might be looking something like this https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extractfield.html but is producer

Comment: That's for Java under Kafka Connect... I'm still not sure I follow what you're trying to ask. But if you want to use that, then you can produce to one topic with no key, then use Connect to extract a field to the key before you write the data to a Connect Sink.

Comment: As I mentioned, though, you can use the Python API to send a key as well.

Comment: Yes I have to extract it from data and put it back in producer before sending.

Comment: we have hardcoded 'IN' , this is not what i am looking for , next data might have different value for countrycode

Comment: I didn't "hard-code" that. I gave an example... You hardcoded it in your console producer... I don't know where the data comes from. The only hardcoded thing I gave was the key for the value.

Comment: ok , thanks a ton , I will try with all the information that you have provided.
and this data will be coming from a http link with a key and username and a password that was provided , this is just sample data that I took

Comment: Thanks , solved my problem and cleared my concepts as well( you know i am new). Thanks , you seems to be active member for kafka issues , do you have a git hub account or a blog to follow.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Thanks for answer, From your answer, I assumed that one cannot send json key and json value via kafka console producer. In confluent 6.2.1, I was able to send json key and json value by separting them with '|' (pipe char) and ksql was able to parse the keys and values. As per your suggestion of using pipe as delimiter.

Comment: @abb I didn't say it wasn't possible. I said that `--key.separator=':'` should be avoided. Version doesn't matter.